# How to get .notify() in chaining promises from $q.all?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am using chained promises in angular js with [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) and it's working fine except the information of *progressCallback* ? let me draw what I have done so far?

calling function from my controller in below chainable promise way

```
fun1()
.then(resp1){
    return fun2(resp1.id);
})
.then(resp2){
    return $q.all([fun3(resp2.id),fun4(resp2.name)]);
})
.then(function(resp34){
    return fun5();
})
.then(success)
.catch(errorhandler)
.finally(final);
```

and here is my all functions signature in service

```
var funX = function(param) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    d.notify('start with funX'); // Note: it was not working so placed inside else
    doSomethingASync(param, function(err,data) {
        if(err) { d.reject(err);}
        else { d.notify('done with funX'); d.resolve(data); }
    });
    return d.promise;
});
```

Now my question is where do I receive this `d.notify()` message in my controller?

**trial 1**

```
.then(resp1, info1){
    return fun2(resp1.id);
});
```

but it's undefined

**trial 2**

```
.then(resp1, err1, info1) {
    return fun2(resp1.id);
}
```

but still undefined?

#### UPDATE

I have find a way by adding second parameter in `finally()`

```
 .then().catch().finally(final, notify);
```

and here is my function definitions.

```
        var errorHandler = function(err) {
           console.error('Error returned from function:', err);
        };

        var final = function() {
            console.log('Called Finally');
        };

        var notify = function(notification) {
            console.log('Notify', notification);
        };

        var success = function(data) {
            console.log('Success data');
            console.log(data);
        };
```

Can we get each promise function notification or this is not feasible?

But Now my query changed to

**How do we add a `.notify` for the `$q.all()` ?**

as I understand that $q.all returns a single promise which contains all promise resolve data;

Comment: You can't use notify with $q.all, to use it you need to manage each promise separately.

Comment: I want to get notification when all promise within `$q.all()` being evaluated ..

Comment: but why not just add the notify message inside the resolve call? using an object {message: "......" , data: data}, resolve and notify are being called at the same time.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.  just calling `return $q.all([..]).then(resp34)` now where should write  `{message:'..', data:data } ` ?

Comment: Instead of doing `d.notify('done with funX'); d.resolve(data);` use `d.resolve({message:'done with funX', data:data })`, then you can use q.all and parse messages and results;